# App with iAds got rejected because the ads didn't show

Tags: ios, iad

I have added iAd support to my app and with that an in app purchase to remove them, when I tested the app on my device and on the simulator it showed the test ads perfectly. I submitted my app for review and now it got rejected, because the ads didn't show and the in app purchase is misleading. What should I do?

I'm using

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

to show the ads.
I did all steps to enable ads in my app, bank accounts, tax info, all that stuff..

Did anyone have a similar problem and if yes, what did you do to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I've got rejected, as well.
I haven't resubmitted yet, but I guess you need to implement iAd delegate methods whether your app works properly or not.

Hope this helps.